# Last 14 days vs before last 14 days data

Tags: sql, postgresql

orders

| id | order_id | created_at | updated_at | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc123 | 2021-06-13 11:00:00 | 2021-06-13 11:00:00 | 230.5 |
| 2 | abc456 | 2021-06-01 07:00:00 | 2021-06-01 07:00:00 | 240 |

To get no of purchases on last 7 days vs before last 7 days I wrote the following query

```
select
    date_trunc('week', created_at) as "Week",
    count(*) "No of purchases"
from orders
```

How can I get no of purchases on last 14 days vs before last 14 days?

Is there a way I can pass like '14 days' or something like that to `date_turnc` method?

If not How Can I write this query?

Comment: Beewekly rounding depends on how you define first day to start from. It has  no standard definition contrary to a week start or a year  start.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use date comparisons?

```
select count(*) as num_purchases
from orders
where created_at >= current_date - interval '14 day'
```

Comment: I believe this only gives for last 14 days

Comment: @AkashJain . . . That is what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the respective intervals from `now()` (or any other function/variable that gives you the right time for the current moment) and compare that to the creation timestamp. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM orders
       WHERE created_at >= now() - '14 days'::interval
             AND created_at < now() - '7 days'::interval;
```

Comment: Is there any other way? because I can't use this query in general to get list of all purchases with 14 day interval

Comment: @AkashJain: If you want all of the last 14 days, just omit the second condition `AND created_at < now() - '7 days'::interval`. Or tweak the numbers if you don't want 7 days but 14 days or whatever, like `created_at >= now() - '28 days'::interval AND created_at < now() - '14 days'::interval`.